# Preloading modules not working with Angular Universal

Tags: angular, angularfire2, angular-universal

I setup Angular Universal in my Firebase app with the following guide: https://github.com/angular/angularfire/blob/master/docs/deploy/getting-started.md

And I started using lazy loading in my Angular Universal app by following this guide: https://angular.io/guide/lazy-loading-ngmodules

I got lazy loading working, but when I got to the end of the guide and tried to preload my modules, I started to get a 404. I didn't get any errors when building or deploying, but got a 404 when trying to load my app.

Here is the relevant code for preloading modules:

```
import { Routes, RouterModule, PreloadAllModules } from '@angular/router';

...

@NgModule({
  imports: [
    RouterModule.forRoot(routes, {
      initialNavigation: 'enabled',
      preloadingStrategy: PreloadAllModules,
    }),
  ],
  exports: [RouterModule],
})
export class AppRoutingModule {}
```

If I remove `preloadingStrategy: PreloadAllModules,`, then the 404 problem goes away. Without any error messages when building/deploying, I can't figure out what the problem is. Is preloading not supported with Universal? Or am I just somehow doing it wrong?

I'm using Angular 9.1.9, Angular Fire 6, and Firebase 7.13.1

Comment: Can you share your repository with this error?

Comment: Please share more details about the scenario, how are you using lazy loading?

Answer (score 0):

it works for me with **Angular9** ( "@angular/core": "9.1.11" ).

I did just:

```
ng add @nguniversal/express-engine
npm run dev:ssr
```

here is the repo with a complete example -
https://github.com/stevermeister/angular9-lazy-loading

Comment: I'm not sure that's what I'm looking for. I'm on Angular 9 and that link says that the content applies to v6 and is no longer supported. Says to reference https://angular.io/guide/universal for versions 7+, which doesn't mention ModuleMapLoaderModule

Comment: thx, for pointing out, I'll try it myself and get back to you